# "a struct has public inheritance by default"

Tags: c++, inheritance

"a struct has public inheritance by default" what does this statement really mean? And why is the following code in error just because I have omitted the keyword 'public' while deriving the class d from c??

```
struct c 
{
protected:
    int i;
public:
    c(int ii=0):i(ii){} 
    virtual c *fun();
};

c* c::fun(){
    cout<<"in c";
    return &c();
}

class d : c
{  
public:
    d(){}
    d* fun()
    {
        i = 9;
        cout<<"in d"<<'\t'<<i;
        return &d();
    }
};


int main()
{
    c *cc;
    d dd;
    cc = &dd;
    cc->fun();
}
```

Comment: don't ignore the warnings the compiler throws at you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means that

```
struct c;
struct d : c
```

is equivalent to

```
struct d : public c
```

Your code is a `class` extending a `struct`:

```
struct c;
class d : c;
```

is equivalent to

```
class d : private c;
```

because `class` has private inheritance by default.

And it means that all inherited and not overriden/overloaded/hidden methods from `c` are private in `d`.

Comment: the error is in the second last line of main `cc = &dd`. Here we are simply assigning the address of the derived class to a pointer to a base class. What has the public and private inheritance to do with it??

Comment: @user1232138 with private inheritance, class `d` is not a `c`.

Comment: There is a mistake in this answer: struct c; class d : c; is equivalent to class d : public c;   "Structs have public inheritance" means that they are publicly inherited by default. Proof: the following code compiles: struct A { int x; };

class B : A {
  void foo() { x = 2; }
};

Comment: @BenoitJacob I know this is an old comment, but it is completely incorrect.  That code compiles because you are accessing `x` from within `class B`.  Accessing `x` from an unrelated scope still fails however.  Proof: [ideone.com/fkX5SN](http://ideone.com/fkX5SN)

Comment: You could add to the first example that it doesn't matter if `c` is a class or a struct. The automatic inheritance depends only on the type of `d`.

Answer (score 6):

"a struct has public inheritance by default" means that this

```
struct Derived : Base {};
```

is equivalent to

```
struct Derived : public Base {};
```

Classes have ***private*** inheritance by default, so when you remove the `public` from a class inheritance you have the equivalent of

```
class Derived : private Base {};
```

In this private inheritance scenario, `Derived` does not have an *is-a* relationship with `Base`, it essentially *has-a* `Base`. So the conversion you are trying to attempt here:

```
cc = &dd;
```

is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a `struct` and inherit from something without specifying an access specifier, that inheritance is treated as `public`. When you write a `class` and inherit from something without specifying an access specifier (even if that something is a `struct`), that inheritance is treated as private. In your code, you're doing the latter, so the inheritance is private, hence the observed error.

Put another way, to say that `struct` inheritance is public by default really means that inheritance done *when writing* a `struct` is public by default, not that inheriting *from* a `struct` is public by default.